# 308 redirect when using POST to upload a file to Flask application

Tags: python-3.x, curl, flask

I am building a small server application in Flask as part of a project I am working on. Part of the functionality is the ability to upload a small file of instructions for one of the key injectors to download. Each key injector has a name (''') which corresponds to a client and the file is uploaded to the server via a POST request.

The following listing is the Flask code.

```
@app.route('/upload/instructions/<ducky_name>/', methods = ['POST'])
def upload_Instruction(ducky_name):
    file = request.files()
    path = os.getcwd() +"/files/" + ducky_name
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write(file)
        print(f)
        f.close()
        return "Success"
```

And I am using this curl command to upload the file.

```
curl -X POST -d @test http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload/instructions/test1
```

I then get a 308 redirect, and the file is not uploaded. This is the first time I've dealt with uploading files as a POST in this way, and the also the first time I've used Flask.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The URL you use in the curl request does not have the trailing slash as in your Flask route. In this case the framework redirects you to the route with slash (see the [documentation entry](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior)). So just add the trailing slash:

```
curl -X POST -d @test http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload/instructions/test1/
```

Flask uses 308 HTTP response code instead of more common 301 to preserve the request method and body during redirect.

Comment: Thanks, that and changing the `request.file` to `request.data` fixed it. Thanks

Comment: And @MartinHarvey you should have accepted this answer or at least upvote it in addition to your "thanks"

Comment: Getting rid of the simple trailer slash from the API helped me even when transmitting a super long utf-8 string as a  param just to test. Matching with a slash from the client also helped but I got a 308 before getting a 200 (I think). Interesting, I don't have time to play with it anymore, but thanks for the help

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Very good,  save 1 day to me!

Answer (score 8):

`Flask` use `werkzeug.routing.Rule`, which enable `strict_slashes` as default, visiting a branch URL without a trailing slash will redirect to the URL with a slash appended. Which cause response with 308 (Permanent Redirect).

If you want to support both routes:

- `/upload/instructions/<ducky_name>/`
- `/upload/instructions/<ducky_name>`

Just set app.route with `strict_slashes=False`, like this:

```
@app.route('/upload/instructions/<ducky_name>/', methods = ['POST'], 
            strict_slashes=False)
def upload_Instruction(ducky_name):
    pass
```

refer: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/routing/